# How to display order data with simple SQL query?

Tags: joomla-4.x, custom-module, jdatabase

I am trying to run a simple query in Joomla 4 to retrieve order data to display in a module.

Testing the query with phpMyAdmin works fine, but despite generating no errors (set to Maximum) the below code returns no rows.

```
$db = Factory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Prepare the query
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM #__orders
          WHERE year(order_date)=" . $orderyear . "
                and month(order_date)=" . $ordermonth . "
                and DAY(order_date)>=" . $beginning . "
                and DAY(order_date)<=" . $enddate . "
          order by order_id desc";
$db->setQuery($query);
// Load the results
$orders = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Phil, what I do not understand in your sql query is that you separately querying year, month and day, on `order_date` field, however you just want back results from the table based on a Date `BETWEEN` interval which could be selected with one `WHERE` line, if I understood your code well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql. So, is there a specific reason why you do not use the simpler approach and why do you need those extra variables for your query on this?

Comment: So your sql query is working without a problem if the correct values are applied in the query and there are corresponding records in the table: You can check here too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37d61a/9

Comment: But I would use this query on your records: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37d61a/10 and then I would convert this to Joomla query as Peter did...

Comment: And as I suspect the reason you get an empty array from this query is because you use four PHP variables in the query and one or more of them is null or has a wrong value. You should check them more. That is the only thing what I see as the real issue in this short post, but we cannot check them from here.

Comment: For volunteers to reproduce the failure, we will need to see a sql fiddle with sample data, and the values that you are using for `$orderyear`, `$ordermonth`, `$beginning`, and `$enddate`. I am noticing that those variables are not quoted, so if they are anything other than integers or float values, your SQL logic/syntax will be compromised.

Answer (score 1):

**Never put variables directly in an SQL query**. That's asking for (SQL injection) problems. Instead use Joomla's query object and escape the variables. Or more advanced: Since Joomla 4 you can use prepared statements.

I would write that code like this (it's without prepared statements)

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$db = Factory::getContainer()->get('DatabaseDriver');
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select('*')
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'))
    ->where('year(order_date) = ' . (int) $orderyear)
    ->where('month(order_date) = ' . (int) $ordermonth)
    ->where('DAY(order_date) >= ' . (int) $beginning)
    ->where('DAY(order_date) <= ' . (int) $enddate)
    ->order('order_id desc');
// The following line is only to display the SQL that you can test in phpMyAdmin
echo $query->dump();

$db->setQuery($query);
$orders = $db->loadObjectList();
```

In the query I made the variables safe by casting them to an integer using `(int)`. Strings can be sanitized with `$db->quote($some_string)`

More info see: https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: Hello Peter and Zollie,, thank you for highlighting my variables mistake...Was not really aware of this as I'm more on the dotnet side than php and would do things a bit differently there. 
As far as Peter's test, it unfortunately does not return any data and I really wonder if this is not a mysql issue. I am using a 5.7 database from my provider. Will try to get it to work with a mySQL 8 version to see if it gets better....

Comment: This SQL logic (transferred from the asked question) may not be reliable when the date range crosses over to another month/year.  Please consider refactoring the SQL as Zollie has recommended with `BETWEEN` and two `Y-m-d` date strings.

Answer (score 0):

The code which works is:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select('*')
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__orders'))
    ->where('YEAR(order_date) = ' . (int) $orderyear)
    ->where('MONTH(order_date) = ' . (int) $ordermonth)
    ->where ('DAY(order_date) BETWEEN ' . (int) $beginning. ' AND ' . (int) $enddate)
    ->order('order_id DESC');
```

I deliberately want to breakout the date so that I can search by year, month or days.

Comment: The code which works is:

 $query = $db->getQuery(true)
  ->select('*')
  ->from($db->quoteName('#__orders'))
  ->where('year(order_date) = ' . (int) $orderyear)
  ->where('month(order_date) = ' . (int) $ordermonth)
  ->where ('DAY(order_date) BETWEEN ' . (int) $beginning. ' and ' . $enddate)
  ->order('order_id desc');

Ivoluntarily want to breakout the date so that I can search by year, month or days.